# How does the app still work when pausing the app?

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

This is my code when I press the volume up button to next / prev songs :

```
    @Override 
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {    
          prevSongs();
       return true;
      } else if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)) { 
          nextSongs();
       return true; 
     } else return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
     }
```

But when the application exits (with the home button to return to the home screen) and I press the volume up button again, it does not work.

How does it work whether it's in or out of the app?

Thank !

Comment: How you play a song? What do you use for that?

Comment: I put it on prevSongs() and nextSongs()

Comment: I used media player, what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a service to handle your playing media. When you exit the app, you can't listen to volume events, but in service you can do it. Also, listening to volume keys to change songs is a bad idea. You should use a notification with actions (buttons).

Comment: I still have not completely escaped the app I still have it running in the recent app, so do I need to create service?